# gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter' does not work in rails with Railway

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, railway

To connect to a SQL Server database from Rails, I had to install a gem:

```rb
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '~> 7.0.0'
```

which in turn requires me to install

```
gem 'tiny_tds', '~> 0.7.0'
```

To make this work, I needed to run `sudo apt-get install freetds-dev` in WSL.
This was sufficient to make it work, and I was able to successfully connect to the remote database.
The issue arises when trying to deploy the API on Railway, where I encounter an error during the build process, presumably because Railway doesn't seem to have `freetds-dev` installed by default.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I thought about sending that command in the "build command," but it didn't work (pepepe).
Alternatively, has anyone been able to connect to a SQL Server database in any other way?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9GMD.png)

Comment: I don't use railway so this suggestion is based solely on the [documentation](https://nixpacks.com/docs/guides/configuring-builds#install-additional-packages) but it appears you can install additional packages by adding them to your build configuration `nixPkgs = ["...", "freetds"]`